# Efficient way to get rows of two arrays that have matching values in fraction of their colums

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Say we have two 2-dimensional arrays, array1 and array2, or alternatively their panda.DataFrame equivalent. For some of the rows in array1, there can be only one or no row in array2 that has equal values in column 2,3, and 4, which I want to extract. That is:

```
array1 = array([[1,4,      5, 656,  1385,   434],
                [11,46,    3, 7356, 585,    74],
                [12,45,    5, 656,  135,    134],
                [112,475,  3, 356,  285,    134],
               ])


array2 = array([[15,44,     5, 656, 1385,   434],
                [151,436,   3, 356, 285,     74],
                [521,406,   5, 656, 135,     24],
                [152,445,   54, 56, 635,     134],
                [72,727,    12, 16, 55,      634]])
```

and what I am looking for is:

```
array1_filtered = array([[1,4,       5, 656,  1385,     434],
                         [112,475,   3, 356,  285,      134],
                         [12,45,     5, 656,  135,      134],
                                               ])
array2_filtered = array([[15,   44,      5, 656, 1385,     434],
                         [151, 436,      3, 356, 285,      74],
                         [521, 406,      5, 656, 135,      24]
                                                ])
```

where both filtered arrays match in terms of their column 2,3, and 4. Even better, have the same matching order in their filtered results like above.

I can think of the following solution but turns out to be quite slow:

```
array1_filtered = []
array2_filtered = []

for row in array1:
    idx = np.where((array2[:, target_columns] == np.array([row[target_columns]])).all(axis=1))[0]
    if idx.size != 0:
        array1_filtered.append(row.tolist())
        array2_filtered.append(array2[idx,:][0].tolist())
array1_filtered  = np.asarray(array1_filtered)
array2_filtered  = np.asarray(array2_filtered)
```

Does anyone know a quicker way using numpy or pandas.DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try pandas:

```
cols = [2,3,4]

s = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([array1,array2])).duplicated(cols, keep=False)

array1_filtered = array1[s.iloc[:len(array1)]]
array2_filtered = array2[s.iloc[-len(array2):]]
```

---

**Update**: Another solution that is slightly better that it doesn't count duplicates *inside* each array:

```
cols = [2,3,4]

s = (pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([array1,array2]))
       .assign(arr_no=[0]*len(array1) + [1]*len(array2))
    )

duplicates = s.groupby(cols).arr_no.transform('nunique')==2

array1_filtered = array1[duplicates[s.arr_no==0]]
array2_filtered = array2[duplicates[s.arr_no==1]]
```

---

**Update**: For the same order of matching:

```
cols = [2,3,4]

s = (pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([array1,array2]))
       .assign(arr_no=[0]*len(array1) + [1]*len(array2))
       .sort_values(cols, kind='mergesort')              # here, sort by `cols`
    )

duplicates = s.groupby(cols).arr_no.transform('nunique')==2

# slicing from s instead of from the original arrays
array1_filtered = s.to_numpy()[duplicates&(s.arr_no==0),:-1]
array2_filtered = s.to_numpy()[duplicates&(s.arr_no==1),:-1]
```

Output:

```
# array1_filtered
array([[ 112,  475,    3,  356,  285,  134],
       [  12,   45,    5,  656,  135,  134],
       [   1,    4,    5,  656, 1385,  434]])

# array2_filtered
array([[ 151,  436,    3,  356,  285,   74],
       [ 521,  406,    5,  656,  135,   24],
       [  15,   44,    5,  656, 1385,  434]])
```

Comment: very efficient solution

Comment: I like your approach but I think you should sort the 2 arrays to respect the condition of having "the same matching order in their filtered results". Also you have a small typo in your last line it should be array2_filtered.

Comment: @QuangHoang the first solution seemed faster no? can you also please recommend a modification that results in the same order of rows for matching columns?

Comment: @Azerila the first option cannot identify duplicates from **within an array** from the duplicates across the arrays. The latter solution only picks those that are occur in both arrays. Will update the solution to yield the same order of matching.

Comment: @Azerila see updated answer for the solution that provide matching in order.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a merge on columns 2, 3 and 4 :

```
cols = [2,3,4]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(array1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(array2)

df_filtered1 = df1.merge(df2.iloc[:,cols], how = 'inner', on = cols).sort_values(cols)
df_filtered2 = df2.merge(df1.iloc[:,cols], how = 'inner', on = cols).sort_values(cols)

# Optional : if you want arrays
array1_filtered = df_filtered1.values
array2_filtered = df_filtered2.values
```